# How to configure a trigger in spring integration flow to get value from a method invoking message source?

Tags: spring-integration

How to configure a trigger in spring integration flow to get value from a method invoking message source and start it in another flow ?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {

   return IntegrationFlows.from(messageSource,channelSpec -> channelSpec.poller(Pollers.trigger(new SomeTrigger())).handle(...).get() 

}
@Bean
public MessageSource<?> messageSource() {
   MethodInvokingMessageSource source = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
   source.setObject(new Random());
   source.setMethod("nextInt");
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow someOtherFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from("messageChannel")
                           ///some logic to trigger and get the value of random int
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MessageSource` has `receive()` method, so you can do just this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<?> randomIntSource() {
    MethodInvokingMessageSource source = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
    source.setObject(new Random());
    source.setMethodName("nextInt");
    return source;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow someOtherFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("messageChannel")
            .handle(randomIntSource(), "receive")
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}
```

pay attention to the `.handle(randomIntSource(), "receive")`.

Comment: To trigger a message source, instead of `from("channel")`, you should use `from(source(), e -> e.poller(...)`.

Comment: But that his original code. See comment in the last `someOtherFliw()`

Comment: Yes, but the question starts with "How to configure a trigger ...", so I think there is a lack of understanding that such a flow does not start with a channel.

Comment: Basically i need some method in the dsl like handle that can access the messages in two different channels.

Comment: One message is coming through the dsl of the same flow and i need to access the message which is present in some other channel.

Comment: Well, that sounds like absolutely different story which deserves its own SO thread